# Android viewpage нужно расположить 5 - 7 фрагментов так чтобы они были видимы на экране

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Стоит задача сделать некоторый горизонтальный скрол в котором будут распологаться компоненты аналогичные кнопкам и при нажатии на одну из них она становиться по центру и под стим скролом открывается еще одно окно. Вообщем взял для этих целей viewpage и сделал под ним лайаут который становиться видимым при нажатии на соответствующий фрагмент во viewpager и но не могу понять как сделать несколько фрагментов на одном экране (5-7 возможно больше)
Количество фрагментов не известно, оно приходит с сервера и нужно динамически сформировать элемнт очень похожий на viewpager но с условием того, что на экране сразу видно 5-7 фрагментов
Может кто подскажет другой виджет который может реализовать данный функционал?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

А что тут размещать, создаете (5-7 возможно больше) фрагментов, дальше в activity прописываете каждый из них вот так например:

```
    <fragment
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:name="com.packagename.ClassFragment0"
                    tools:layout="@layout/you_fragment_layout0" />
    <fragment
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:name="com.packagename.ClassFragment1"
                    tools:layout="@layout/you_fragment_layout1" />
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать готовую библиотеку с гитхаба [вот тут](https://github.com/Pixplicity/MultiViewPager)

Comment: Спасибо за хорошую библиотеку!
Может кто подскажет как можно добавить OnClickListener к выделенному элементу, а то пробую переопределить instantiateItem у адаптера а мне постоянно выскакивает java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem